# Separador de miles

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta consulta

```
  SELECT CONVERT(numeric(18,0), CAST((g.SI_Existencia) * gg.SI_Costo_Promedio AS MONEY),1) 
  from SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD g
  INNER JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD gg ON g.SI_Articulo = gg.SI_Num_Articulo
  WHERE SI_Articulo = 200038
```

Estoy tratando de hacer que el resultado me lo muestre en separador de miles tanto los campos `g.SI_Existencia` y `gg.SI_Costo_Promedio` son  `numeric(18,0)`

```
g.SI_Existencia = 58
gg.SI_Costo_Promedio = 41040.010
```

Comment: Esto es algo que realmente no tiene mucho sentido de hace a nivel de base de datos, sino que en la presentación

Answer (score 2):

Eduard tal como lo manifestó Salo en su respuesta me gustaría agregar lo siguiente a la instrucción FORMAT.

Si el valor esperado en la consulta lo quiere sin decimales puede escribirla así:

```
   Format(gg.SI_Costo_Promedio , 'N0', 'en-us') = 41040
```

Si el valor esperado en la consulta lo quiere con decimales puede escribirla así:

```
   Format(gg.SI_Costo_Promedio , 'N2', 'en-us') = 41040.01
```

El número de decimales que espero que me muestre debo ponerlo en el formato de la sentencia FORMAT.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar FORMAT(Valor, 'Formato')
Donde 'Formato' puede ser N o C

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh213505(v=sql.120).aspx

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

```
select format(12354.46 , '#,##0')
select format(123533244.46 , '#,##0.00')
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer].